# How to display a numerical ratings system in a Tradingview table?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Trying to display a ratings system in a Tradingview table.

Basically, we have 2 parameters, say, “A" & “B”.

A can have ratings from 0 to 4 (i.e. any one of 0,1,2,3,4).

Similarly, B can have ratings from 0 to 4 (i.e. any one of 0,1,2,3,4).

//Example of A Ratings

```
AFour = (A>EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13)
AThree = (A>EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13)
ATwo = (A<EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13)
AOne = (A<EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13)
```

//Example of B Ratings

```
BFour = (B>EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13)
BThree = (B>EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13)
BTwo = (B<EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13)
BOne = (B<EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13)
```

I wish to translate these text values to numbers e.g. AFour translates to the number 4.

And then, add the A & B ratings, & display them as a final number. e.g. If the rating is AThree & BTwo, the final rating displays as 5.

Progess so far is that I’ve only been able to display the A & B ratings in a table.

```
if(AFour == true)
    table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = "4", bgcolor = color.blue, text_color = color.white)

if(AFour == false)
    if(AThree == true)
        table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = "3", bgcolor = color.green, text_color = color.white)
    if(AThree == false)
        if(ATwo == true)
            table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = "2", bgcolor = color.orange, text_color = color.black)
        if(ATwo == false)
            if(AOne == true)
                table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = "1", bgcolor = color.red, text_color = color.black)
            if(AOne == false)
                table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 1, text = "0", bgcolor = #F7E98E, text_color = color.black)
```

But I am unable to add the ratings & display their sum total.

Comment: What's your question or what is wrong with the code you shared?

Comment: I am unable to add the ratings & display their sum total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you could try for example

```
AFour = (A>EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13) ? 1 : 0
AThree = (A>EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13) ? 1 : 0
ATwo = (A<EMA5 and EMA5>EMA13) ? 1 : 0
AOne = (A<EMA5 and EMA5<EMA13) ? 1 : 0
    
Atotal = AFour + AThree + ATwo + AOne

if Atotal == 0
// do something
else if Atotal == 1
// do something
...
else if Atotal == 4
// do something
```

Do the same for the Bs and you'll have your As and Bs rating